# Unable to fetch array element and save to database

Tags: php

I would like to be able to draw array data into a tabular format in html, just for my reference to learn. When i use following code, it shows that the data exists for an array

```html
$array_att_logs = $logs3->to_array(); 
    echo " <pre>"; 
    print_r($array_att_logs); 
    echo "/<pre>"; 
    
    // it shows array as follow
    
    Array
(
    [Row] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [PIN] => 1274
                    [DateTime] => 2018-04-07 09:28:16
                    [Verified] => 15
                    [Status] => 3
                    [WorkCode] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [PIN] => 157
                    [DateTime] => 2018-04-07 10:22:56
                    [Verified] => 15
                    [Status] => 3
                    [WorkCode] => 0
                )
    // these are the raw punch data from biometric machine
```

With the following code and some work around, it either throws error with undefined index, array to string conversion, or undefined offset...sorry I am a newbie to both programming as well as forum world.

```html
if(isset($array_att_logs) && $array_att_logs != NULL){
                        
   foreach ($array_att_logs as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $array_att_logs['PIN'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $array_att_logs['DateTime'] ."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";  

 $punch_query = "INSERT INTO punching_data_table (pin,date_time) 
                            VALUES('$PIN','$value')";
$punch_result = mysql_query($punch_query)
  }
}
```

Answers with explanation on the sample code will be really appreciated.

Comment: Use `$value ['PIN']` there is no `$array_att_logs['PIN']`. Do not use `mysql_` functions.  Use mysqli or pdo with prepared statements and placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top level element of your array is one with the index `Row`, so you should change your `foreach` loop to `foreach ($array_att_logs['Row'] as $key => $value) { ... }`.

The second part is what mickmackusa already pointed out in a comment, you need to use the local variable `$value` to access the pin and the datetime.

You also don't need to check for `null` after `isset(...)`, because that is what `isset` is doing already. Better check for existence of the `Row` index.

As a final result, you should be able to get it working with the following code piece:

```
if(isset($array_att_logs) && isset($array_att_logs['Row'])) {                     
    foreach ($array_att_logs['Row'] as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $value['PIN'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $value['DateTime'] ."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";  

        $punch_query = "INSERT INTO punching_data_table (pin, date_time) VALUES ('$value['PIN']', '$value['DateTime']')";
        $punch_result = mysql_query($punch_query)
    }
}
```

---

I also advice you to have a look at reserved words in MySQL ([see documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)). Your `DateTime` column uses one of these names, which should be avoided. Better use a more descriptive name like `CreatedAt`, `UpdatedAt` or `MeasuredAt`. It would also be a good idea to move on from the old `mysql_` functions to `mysqli_` functions or `PDO`, as a next step (due to security issues with `mysql_` and also because they are deprecated).

Comment: Thanks buddy ...kinda gotta for the tabular format but when it came to insertion in the table, it threw following error.  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\......\filename.php on line 97  ill be careful about reserved words, though the DateTime column is from the device I have no control of. In my database, I have defined it as date_time which I guess it doesn't conflict with. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you give me an idea what is written on line 97 in `filename.php`?

Comment: line no 97 -->  $punch_query = "INSERT INTO punching_data_table (pin, date_time) VALUES ('$value['PIN']', '$value['DateTime']')";
line no 98 -->  $punch_result = mysql_query($punch_query);

Comment: Is your pin a numeric field in the database? Then maybe just remove the `'` around `$value['PIN']` in the query.

Comment: removed ' around $value['PIN'] but still no luck, same error. Yes, pin is set as integer in database. If I am not wrong to interpret it correctly, it says double quote " is unexpected.

Comment: line no 97 now looks like --->     $punch_query = "INSERT INTO punching_data_table (pin, date_time) VALUES ($value['PIN'], '$value['DateTime']')";         date_time is defined as DateTime in database just FYI please.

Comment: Oh yeah, there shouldn't be single quotes for the array access when accessed directly in double quotes. So try this: `$punch_query = "INSERT INTO punching_data_table (pin, date_time) VALUES ($value[PIN], '$value[DateTime]')";`

Comment: @vPtel Generally, you should be using the single quotes on your keys.   Wrap your values in curly braces.    `{$value['PIN']}`

Comment: @Namoshek `if(isset($array_att_logs) && isset($array_att_logs['Row']))` can be condensed to `if (isset($array_att_logs, $array_att_logs['Row']))` with the same meaning.  Or most logically, just call `if(isset($array_att_logs['Row']))` ...because if the subarray key exists, then the parent array exists.  This is most direct and Notice-free.  Also, you should not declare `$key` because it is not used.

Comment: @Namoshek As a matter of role modeling good coding practices, please avoid using mysql_ functions in your answers.  This will influence the OP and future researchers to stop using old deprecated functions.

Comment: I agree that it is bad coding practice, hence the hint to not use these functions at the end of my post. The problem with suddenly using mysqli or pdo in an answer is that the question asker will have even more trouble implementing the solution than before.  So it is a bit of a trade-off situation.

Comment: @Namoshek, sorry asking again for the answered question. Actually, I am getting illegal string offset error message when [0]=> array in var_dump above but if there is more than zero then no problem.  Can I check if [1]=>array exists then execute code otherwise false.
(
    [Row] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [PIN] => 1274
                    [DateTime] => 2018-04-07 09:28:16
                    [Verified] => 15
                    [Status] => 3
                    [WorkCode] => 0
                )

Comment: Sure, you can always use `isset($array['named_index'])` or `count($array) > 0` for such cases. There is also a lot of material (Q&A) out there already for this issues.

Comment: @Namoshek thanks buddy already tried that and now realized the problem is not on array part but insert statement..sorry. Illegal offset string is caused on line no 93 which is insert statement saying illegal offset string  'PIN' & 'DateTime'. Latest Insert statement as below. $punch_query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO punching_data_table (emp_code, date_time,in_out_status) VALUES ($value[PIN], '$value[DateTime]','$in_out_status')";  this query works just fine if there is more than 1 insert but if only 1 exists then the error is displayed.

Comment: It is hard to help here in the comments with such problems. Please post a new question with properly formatted code and a detailed problem description.

Comment: @Namoshek I have posted a new question with properly formatted code and detailed description here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200209/unable-to-insert-into-mysql-table-due-to-wrong-array-datatype   please help if possible.