# unable to insert into mysql table due to wrong array datatype

Tags: php, mysql

Following is the array from which the data are retrieved and tried to be inserted into mysql table but works well when more than 1 row to be inserted and fails when only 1 row to be inserted.

```
// The structure of the array is as follows
Array
(
    [Row] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [PIN] => 1274
                    [DateTime] => 2018-04-07 09:28:16
                    [Verified] => 15
                    [Status] => 3
                    [WorkCode] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [PIN] => 157
                    [DateTime] => 2018-04-07 10:22:56
                    [Verified] => 15
                    [Status] => 3
                    [WorkCode] => 0
                )
    // these are the raw punch data from biometric machine
```

Following is the piece of code which currently being used.

```
  if(isset($array_att_logs) && isset($array_att_logs['Row'])) {     
      foreach ($array_att_logs['Row'] as $value) {
          $emp_code =  $value['PIN'];       // line 92                                  $dateNTime =  $value['DateTime']; //line 93

$punch_query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO punching_data_table (emp_code, date_time,in_out_status) VALUES ('$emp_code', '$dateNTime','$in_out_status')";

 $punch_result = mysql_query($punch_query);
 echo mysql_error();
         }       
     } echo var_dump($array_att_logs);
```

Please note that the $in_out_status is defined explicitly elsewhere which does not seem to have any problem at all.I have checked using `var_dump()` that the array exists with data just fine. The problem is if there is a single row to be inserted into the table then following error is shown.

> ```
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'PIN' in /home1/.../punch-raw.php on line 92
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'DateTime' in /home1/..../punch-raw.php on line 93
> ```

If there is more than 1 row to be inserted into the table then it works just fine. May be I am defining `$emp_code` and `$dateNTime` incorrectly.

Here is how it looks like when there is a single row.

```html
 echo " <pre>"; 
    print_r($array_att_logs); 
    echo "/<pre>"; 

Array
(
    [Row] => Array
        (
            [PIN] => 406
            [DateTime] => 2018-05-06 14:40:09
            [Verified] => 1
            [Status] => 3
            [WorkCode] => 0
        )

)
/

using var_dump it looks like below

array(1) { ["Row"]=> array(5) { ["PIN"]=> string(3) "406" ["DateTime"]=> string(19) "2018-05-06 14:40:09" ["Verified"]=> string(1) "1" ["Status"]=> string(1) "3" ["WorkCode"]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

Comment: The error message is saying that `$value` is a string, not an array. Have you checked what the array looks like when there is only one row in it?

Comment: @Nick question updated with how it looks like when there is only one row in it.

Comment: So indeed the array structure is different, `$array_att_logs['Row']` is no longer an array of arrays, it is just an array. Hence your foreach loop assigns the values `406`, `2018-05-06 14:40:09`, etc. to `$value`, which are strings, and hence the error you are getting. So you need to figure out how to make the structure consistent regardless of the number of rows. i.e. for one row it should look like `Array ( [Row] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [PIN] => 406 etc. etc.`

Comment: @Nick can I instead place a check to make sure that the insert is executed only if no of rows is more than 1. For example, if $array_att_row['Row']> 0 then execute the insert else false.

Comment: Surely you will want to do that insert? Otherwise you will lose the data? But if you have a count of the rows you could use that to control the foreach instead, make it `foreach ($array_att_logs as $value`) when there is only one row.

Comment: @Nick `for each ($array_att_logs as $value)` works fine when there is a single row and the same throws error as undefined index 'PIN' and undefined index 'DateTime' when there is more than 1 row. I also tried `count($array_att_logs) but it doesn't help either as count is always 1. If I can somhow manage to bypass insert when there is 1 row, it is fine as I would display message to the user that there is 1 row and try agan to downlod when the row is more than 1 which time first one will be downloaded too. Usually users going to download when there is bulk data but 1 row we can not avoid either.

Comment: I think I know how to make it work I'll write it up as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you are having the problem is that the array structure of `$array_att_logs` is different when there is only 1 row to when there are more than one row. Thus you need to test for that situation and change the way you iterate through the array. The easiest way to check if there is only 1 row is to see if the contents of $array_att_logs['Row'] is an array of arrays. To do this we use `array_values($array_att_logs['Row'])` to ensure that we have an entry with an index of 0, and then test that value to see if it is an array. Then we use that result to change the value being iterated by the foreach:

```
$row = array_values($array_att_logs['Row']);
$multirows = is_array($row[0]);
foreach (($multirows ? $array_att_logs['Row'] : $array_att_logs) as $value) {
    $emp_code =  $value['PIN'];
    ...
```